# How to get rid of Android Studio warning "Result of getException() not thrown"?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following method:

```
private void recoverPassword() {

    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();        

    mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail("mail@example.com").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Exception e = task.getException();
                System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    });

}
```

And I keep getting Android Studio warning:

> Result of 'getException()' not thrown

How can I rewrite the snippet above to get rid of that warning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a `SuppressWarnings` annotation to the method:

```
        @SuppressWarnings("ThrowableResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Exception e = task.getException();
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
```

Android Studio will help you with this:

1. Place the cursor on `getException()`
2. Type `Alt-Enter`
3. Click on `Inspection 'Throwable result of method call ignored' options`
4. Click on `Suppress for Method` (or any other option you prefer)